# Get a List of New Releases

Tags: spotify

When using the endpoint https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/new-releases the documentation says that country is optional.

> Optional. A country: an ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code. Provide this parameter if you want the list of returned items to be relevant to a particular country. If omitted, the returned items will be relevant to all countries.

When trying this, leaving out the country parameter, i get zero items back. I've tried this in my own code and on https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/get-new-releases/ with the same result.

My question is, how do i get back items relevant for all countries?

https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-list-new-releases/

Comment: Thanks for reporting this - a more appropriate place to track this is the public issue tracker at https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues. We're looking into this now though.